# Javascript function not being called properly

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function

```
function createHyperLinkDraft(){ 
    var xWin = window.opener;
    var hyperLink = document.addHyperLinkForm.hyperLinkNameDraft.value;

    if(hyperLink){

        var urlList = "openDraftFilesAction.action?draftID="+ document.addHyperLinkForm.DraftNo.value ;
        hyperLinkName = "&nbsp;<a style='text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer' onclick=javascript:window.open('"+urlList+"','subWindow','HEIGHT=600,WIDTH=600,screenX=100,left=100,screenY=100,top=100')>"+ hyperLink +"</a>&nbsp;";

        xWin.Xinha._currentlyActiveEditor.insertHTML(hyperLinkName);

        document.addHyperLinkForm.reset();
        window.close();
    }
}
```

This is getting stored in the noting editor. but when I see in my action class its getting stored as

```
<p>l&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:window.open('openDraftFilesAction.action? draftID=9/1021/2015-FT-COORD-new" 3?,?subwindow?,?height="600,WIDTH=600,screenX=100,left=100,screenY=100,top=100')" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline">link</a>&nbsp;</p>
```

Where say actual draft id was 9/1021/2015-FT-COORD-new file 12oct/3.

Hence, this draft is not being opened. I can't understand why is this happening.

Comment: Do you have the last bracket closed?

Comment: Create a fiddle and reproduce the error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode it using `encodeURIComponent()`

From MDN:

> The **encodeURIComponent()** method encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

```
function createHyperLinkDraft() { 
    var xWin = window.opener;
    var hyperLink = document.addHyperLinkForm.hyperLinkNameDraft.value;

    if (hyperLink) {
        var urlID = document.addHyperLinkForm.DraftNo.value;
        urlID = encodeURIComponent(urlID);
        var urlList = "openDraftFilesAction.action?draftID="+ urlID;
        hyperLinkName = "&nbsp;<a style='text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer' onclick=javascript:window.open('"+urlList+"','subWindow','HEIGHT=600,WIDTH=600,screenX=100,left=100,screenY=100,top=100')>"+ hyperLink +"</a>&nbsp;";

        xWin.Xinha._currentlyActiveEditor.insertHTML(hyperLinkName);

        document.addHyperLinkForm.reset();
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It helped, but can you explain what is encodeURIComponent?

Comment: i added it in the answer. it is a standard javascript function.

Comment: Actually there is a problem in it, In the first time, the link does not get opened. But, on refreshing the page its getting opened

Comment: can you just add window.open(urlList); just to see if it is a problem of your xWin object or directly a link problem? there are little information to understand the problem here.